# Automatically downcast function arguments in C++

Tags: c++, inheritance, casting

I have two classes, let's say Base and Derived:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {};
```

and a function foo:

```
auto foo (Derived* d) {
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to automatically downcast its argument? So I could do something like this:

```
Base* b = new Derived();
foo(b);
```

Basically I would like to write this without explicit casting it before function call.
I read something about conversion operators/constructors but they seem not useful in my case, do you have any other idea?

Edit: Sorry, I oversimplified the question with 2 classes and just a function. But actually I've got a library of 50-ish functions and 3 classes (a superclass and 2 subclasses). This unfortunately makes the easiest and cleanest solutions unsuitable because in my opinion (correct me if I am wrong) they scale bad.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174695/discussion-on-question-by-ale-automatically-downcast-function-arguments-in-c).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three possible solutions, depending on your needs. I've replaced raw pointers with `unique_ptr`s in my examples.

### Case 1: You don't need the base type of each derived type to be the same.

Use [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to allow the base type to invoke itself as a derived type. Example implementation:

```
template <typename DerivedType>
class Base {
    template <typename F>
    auto invoke_as_derived(F&& f) {
        return std::forward<F>(f)(static_cast<DerivedType*>(this));
    }
};
class Derived : public Base<DerivedType> {};
```

Usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base<Derived>> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
b->invoke_as_derived(foo);
```

Since you mentioned using a list of Base pointers, this probably won't work for you.

### Case 2: You need a shared base type but only have one layer in your type hierarchy and no virtual methods.

Use [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) and [`std::visit`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit).

```
class Derived {};
using Base = std::variant<Derived, /* other derived types */>;

auto foo(Derived*) { ... }

class FooCaller {
    operator ()(Derived& d) {
        return foo(&d);
    }
    // Overload for each derived type.
}
```

Usage:

```
Base b = Derived();
std::visit(FooCaller{}, b);
```

### Case 3: You need a single base type but also want virtual methods and/or additional layers in your type hierarchy.

You might try the [visitor pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern). It takes some boilerplate, but it may be the best solution depending on your needs. Sketch of the implementation:

```
class Visitor; // Forward declare visitor.

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void accept(Visitor& v) = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void accept(Visitor& v) final { v.visit(*this); }
};

struct Visitor
{
    virtual void visit(Derived&) = 0;
    // One visit method per derived type...
};
struct FooCaller : public Visitor
{
    // Store return value of call to foo in a class member.
    decltype(foo(new Derived())) return_value;

    virtual void visit(Derived& d)
    {
        return_value = foo(&d);
    }
    // Override other methods...
};
```

Usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<Base> b = std::make_unique<Derived>();
FooCaller foo_caller;
b->accept(foo_caller);
```

You could write a visitor that takes a function to apply to the element so you don't have to repeat this for all of your many functions. Alternatively, if you can alter the functions themselves, you could replace your functions with visitor types.

### Edit: Simplifying the call syntax back down to `foo(b)`

Define an overload per function overload set to which you want to pass `Base` objects. Example, using the 3rd technique:

```
auto foo(Base* b) {
    FooCaller foo_caller;
    b->accept(foo_caller);
    return std::move(foo_caller.return_value);
}
```

Now `foo(b.get())` will delegate to the appropriate overload of `foo` at run-time.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, even though this doesn't entirely solve my problem. Maybe I should have put more emphasis on the fact that my goal is to do a plain function call like `foo(b)` without adding more logic around. Otherwise I would simply do `foo(dynamic_cast<Derived*>(b))`.
Anyway, since you proposed different solution that I didn't know of and that could possibly/partially work, I'm gonna accept your answer

Comment: If the syntax at the call site is really important, you could define one overload per function name, taking a `Base` pointer/variant, and then delegate to the real overload inside using one of the above techniques. I'll edit an example into my answer.

Comment: Great and complete answer.... but this guy might just be learning C++ and just needs a virtual member function. Often on SO questions are in fact XY problems.

Comment: You know, the CRTP can be derived from a common base-type... and what is `class FooCaller(Base)`?

Comment: Oops, copy-paste error. Fixed. And you're right - the 1st and 3rd approaches can be combined to reduce boilerplate while maintaining the common base type.

Answer (score 1):

The usual approach would not be to downcast, but to use virtual functions. I.e. put `void foo()` *inside* of the class.

```
#include<iostream>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() { std::cout << "Base foo()\n"; }
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() override { std::cout << "Derived foo()\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived();
    b->foo();
    delete b;
}
```

outputs:

```
Derived foo()
```

If you want to make it impossible to call `Base::foo()`, you can set

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
```

making `Base` an abstract class.

But if you *really* want to call `foo(b)`, you can use a (templated) helper function. E.g.:

```
#include<iostream>
class Base {
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;
    virtual void foo() = 0;
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    void foo() override {
        std::cout << "Derived foo()\n";
    }
};

template<typename T>
void foo(T* t)
{
    t->foo();
}

int main()
{
    Base* b = new Derived();
    foo(b);
    delete b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but as I said in previous comments I got 50 or more functions to be treated like this and also 2 derived classes. So I guess this approach would scale bad

Comment: @Ale I see no comments. You should add that information in your question. You need to provide us with full information, else we're just guessing here...

Comment: It's in the chat originated from the comments section of the question, in response to another user that already suggested your solution. 
I'll add this extra information to the question though